# Check default printer is on or not

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing, .net-2.0

How can i figure out whether default printer is on or not using vb.net or C# (on .Net 2.0)

And what is the port number to which printer is attached.

I am using PrinterSettings Class, but there is no method in it to get those values.

Answer (score 1):

You can get port number using this code.

```
private void cboPrinters_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  PrintQueue printer = cboPrinters.SelectedItem as PrintQueue;
  string portname = printer.QueuePort.Name;
}
```

Comment: thanks but PrintQueue is not supported in .Net 2.0.
Any other way?

Comment: Check this link if it can help.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6069/How-to-Check-if-your-Printer-is-Connected-using-C

Comment: Hey try this link [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6069/How-to-Check-if-your-Printer-is-Connected-using-C)

Comment: @Priscy,@Neeraj Dubey:  Guys the link you mention above uses System.Management which is not supported by .Net 2.0.  Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Following:**

```
string strDefaultPrinter;
using(var printServer = new LocalPrintServer())
{
  strDefaultPrinter= printServer.DefaultPrintQueue.FullName);
}
```

In this way you can set default printer in one string and can compare with detected printer.

Comment: But how do i detect whether default printer is on or off?

Comment: here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001920/c-sharp-check-printer-status

Comment: I am using .Net 2.0, your solution works with .Net 3.0 or above., Is there any other method?

Comment: @Sudz sorry friend, I dont know for 2.0, also googled, but not found.