# Checking if print was successful

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Windows Forms application, printing is done by creating process with command. I want to get error messages when printing fails, is this possible?

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath)
{
    Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Verb = "PrintTo"
};
Process.Start(info);
```

Tried to use `System.Printing.PrintSystemJobInfo` to determine print outcome, but is not possible to determine from it, since it never get status `IsCompleted`. And print job disappears quickly.

Also tried to change print process to:

```
var printQueue = FindPrintQueue(printerName);
printQueue.Refresh(); 
PrintSystemJobInfo job = printQueue.AddJob(filePath, filePath, false);
```

But in this case printing job is created but the printing has the status "Spooling" and document is not printed at all.

Comment: Maybe the top rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001920/c-sharp-check-printer-status) will help?

Comment: If you want interaction with the printing process, you should use the [PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=net-5.0) functionality.