# Check printer out of paper before sending a job

Tags: c#, printing, status

i'm trying to get information of a printer. Using WMI i can retrieve some information but only if a job has been sent.

I need to check if my printer is out of paper before sending a job.

Is this possible?

Comment: dont you already have 1 question up with this?

Comment: Here's your previous question WITH answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455964/c-sharp-printer-properties-wmi. Here's the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It's a diferent question.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. You got answers the last time, and there is prior information on SO! CHEERS!

Comment: It's not the same question as you can read.BEFORE sending a job. WMI only viable when a job has been sent.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself but have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isoutofpaper.aspx

Answer (score 0):

check DetectedErrorState property, 3 is low paper, 4 is no paper, 5 is low toner

Comment: you can get printer status from Win32_Printer before send a job.

Answer (score 0):

This is how  i did it...

```
   //check PAPER OK and Toner OK
    private static bool IspaperOK(ManagementBaseObject printer)
    {
        bool PaperOK = true;

        string[] printers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModelliStampanti"].Trim().Split('#');

        foreach (var property in printer.Properties)
        {

            if (property.Name == "DeviceID")
            {
                var PaperStatus = printer.Properties["PrinterState"].Value.ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i <= printers.Length - 1; i++)
                {

                    if (property.Value.ToString() == printers[i].ToString())
                    {     //131072 = Toner Low
                          //1024 = printing
                          //16 = Out of Paper
                          //5 = out of paper
                          //128 - offline(no internet connection)   


                          //this is for out of paper....
                        if ((PaperStatus == "5") ||(PaperStatus == "16"))
                        {
                            PaperOK = false;
                        }

                        //this is for low toner....
                        if (PaperStatus == "131072")
                        {
                            PaperOK = false;
                        }

                    }

                }


            }

        }
        return PaperOK;
    }
```

To verify these problems use these values instead of values described in MSDN

```
                //131072 = Toner Low
                //1024 = printing
                //16 = Out of Paper
                //5 = out of paper
                //128 - offline(no internet connection OR printer turned off )
```