# Printing Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, printing, crystal-reports

I am facing a problem in printing Crystal Reports in Windows Forms app. Normal application flow is working like charm but I want to handle the situation when printer is not available or is not ready for printing. I was looking for WMI but I am facing problem like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455964/c-sharp-printer-properties-wmi/18214802#18214802), that my printer always return `Status 3 or State 0 (idle)`. Now I am looking for exceptions of `PrinttoPrinter` method of Crystal Reports but yet no luck. Any idea will be appreciated.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

In above article link, `ConfigManagerErrorCode` is option given as a status of your current printer.

you can check whenever the 0 value comes, then you only give the printToprinter command else give custom or printer error method based on the value you retrieve.

[Win32_Printer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%20(search%20above%20keyword))