# PRINTER_INFO_6 not available using WIn32 api

Tags: winapi, printing, pywin32

I have been trying to get printer status from a DNP rx1 printer, but the status of the printer does not change when I open the tray of the printer. Here is an example using py32win library to access the status and it always return status = 0 event when the tray is open.

```
device_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(device_name)

# Get the default properties for the printer
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
```

When I try `win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 6) # 6 = print_info_6` I get the some NotImplementedException. So my guess is that the firmware of the printer have not implemented print_info_6. So I can't get the status from the printer

I have also tried using powershell with:

```
Get-Printer | Select Name, PrinterStatus
```

Also no change in status when I open the tray or if there is a paper jam.

Is there anything that I'm overlooking? Is there anything else I can try to get the status of the printer?

Comment: Hi torbacka, I can't reproduce this issue in C++ on Windows 10. Could you check my answer and provide your OS version information and try the pause operation to see if you can get `PRINTER_STATUS_PAUSED` status code?

Comment: Hi @RitaHan-MSFT, thanks for your answers. I don't have access to the printer right now, but I'm quite sure it would show paused if I press the pause button. I found this stack overflow post and I think my printers firmware just don't send the information to the spoolsv.exe.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18214802/12727331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PRINTER_INFO_6`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-info-6) works for me in C++ on Windows 10 1903 with OneNote printer.

[image]

And when I pause the printer I get status `0x00000001` ([PRINTER_STATUS_PAUSED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rprn/1625e9d9-29e4-48f4-b83d-3bd0fdaea787)).

[image]

The C++ code I used for testing.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Winspool")

int main()
{
    DWORD bufSize;
    WCHAR* buf = NULL;
    HANDLE hPrinter = NULL;
    PRINTER_INFO_6 info = {};
    DWORD needed;
    BOOL result = FALSE;
    DWORD err;

    // Get required buffer size
    result = GetDefaultPrinter(NULL, &bufSize);
    if(!result)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != err)
        {
            std::cout << "GetDefaultPrinter failed with error: \n" << GetLastError();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    buf = (WCHAR*)calloc(bufSize, sizeof(WCHAR));
    result = GetDefaultPrinter(buf, &bufSize);
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "GetDefaultPrinter failed with error: \n" << GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    std::wcout << "Printer name: " << buf << "\n";
    result = OpenPrinter(buf, &hPrinter, NULL);
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "OpenPrinter failed with error: \n" << GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    result = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 6, (LPBYTE)&info, sizeof(PRINTER_INFO_6), &needed);
    if (!result)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != err)
        {
            std::cout << "GetPrinter failed with error: \n" << GetLastError();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    BYTE* statBuf = (BYTE*)calloc(needed, sizeof(BYTE));
    result = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 6, statBuf, needed, &needed);
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "GetPrinter failed with error: \n" << GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Printer status (low 32bit): " << *((DWORD*)statBuf) << "\n";
    statBuf += sizeof(DWORD);
    std::cout << "Printer status (high 32bit): " << *((DWORD*)statBuf) << "\n";

    getchar();
}
```

Some issues I found in testing:

1. Pinter status defined as a `DWORD` (4 bytes) in [`PRINTER_INFO_6` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-info-6) but `GetPrinter` requries 8 bytes for it (`needed == 8`). So you will get `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` error when you pass a `PRINTER_INFO_6` structure as `pPrinter` parameter.
2. There is only `PRINTER_INFO_6` defined but no `_PRINTER_INFO_6W` (Unicode) and `_PRINTER_INFO_6A` (ANSI) mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-info-6).

Comment: Will try your solution and see if it helps getting the printer status, but I'm afraid my printer just does not send information about status to the spoolsv.exe.